# Restricting WebAPI functions to users who are authorized?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, react-redux

I was running an asp.net core webapp that used individual user authentication so they could sign up and use various features on the website.

I'm trying to move towards a React+Redux front end with a WebAPI backend where the WebAPI will contain all the server side features including the user login details.

Unfortunately it looks like Asp.net Core does not support authentication with individual user accounts locally.

Is there a way around this? Is what I'm doing even possible?

Perhaps an alternative option would be to use the same Asp.Net Core web application project as a sort of 'back end' which the React+Redux project front end can connect to through calls to the controllers. Is that feasible?

Comment: What about a custom attribute to check the permissions of the auth token accessing the resource?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean.. The way I set up the Asp.Net website was through an option when creating the project. Obviously I have to roll my own solution now but I'm not sure how to go about it...

Comment: Do you already have any roles defined for your users?

Answer (score 0):

I think that's feasible, check out this article, it might help

https://medium.com/@MaartenSikkema/using-react-redux-and-webpack-with-dotnet-core-to-build-a-modern-web-frontend-7e2d091b3ba